# Moving the body with fixed elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed

If I animate the `body` of my document

```
$('body').animate({'margin-left': '500px'});
```

All of my fixed elements won't move:

```
.box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

If I want everything in my document to move, will I need to move fixed elements independently of the body, or is there a way I can make the elements fixed to the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how fixed positioned elements work - they are positioned relative to the viewport.

See the [CSS 2.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning):

> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport. For continuous media, fixed boxes do not move when the document is scrolled. In this respect, they are similar to fixed background images.

You might animate `left` or `margin-left` properties of the the fixed elements too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('*').animate({'margin-left': '500px','left': '500px'});`.  The `*` selector matches EVERYTHING.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with every element on a page since it will utilize the CPU very much. Futher: setting a margin to any element might break the function (design) of many elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `fixed` elements to `absolute` positioning, and your `body` element to `relative` positioning.

That way, all elements will be moved in relation to the body:

```js
$('body').animate({'margin-left': '500px'});
```

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum &hellip;
</p>
```